# Proper usage of 'if so' in a sentence

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-ends

I have used a sentence today like below but not sure I used *if so* correctly here;

> Additionally, we could make your
>   booking via e-mail if you prefer to
>   proceed that way. Please let us know
>   if so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would just move this around slightly:

> ...we could make your booking via e-mail if you prefer to proceed that way; if so, please let us know.

Or, you could re-word to get the same meaning:

> ...if you prefer, upon request we could make your booking via e-mail.

Comment: the first one is a good example for me. I was thinking to open another question about the usage of semi-colon `;`. Now I see it can be used in sentences in English.

Comment: @tugberk: [The Oatmeal](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/semicolon) to the rescue...

Comment: @Tragicomic  hehe :) I wasn't aware of that website. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You used it correctly.

There is a slight addition I would implement to make it clearer:

> Please let us know if it is so.

That way, there can be no misunderstanding.

Comment: ok but it raises another question : which one is correct? **If it is so** or **if so**?

Comment: @tugberk - they're semantically identical; "if so" is simply a shorter form, while "if it is so" or "if this is so" is longer but maybe a little clearer depending on context.